# How to define inner polygon in coco dataset?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, faster-rcnn, semantic-segmentation

I'm looking to understand how to define inner or interior polygon in segmentation part of coco dataset

I'd like to teach the convolution network to recognize holes in building polygons

Example of the polygon with hole

[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific? May be an expected input / expected output?

Comment: The mask has a holes. I guess this implies two lists, one for the outer contour, and one for the inner contour.Or two overlapping masks: one for the object and one for the hole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution is to define shapes with holes using RLE (Run Length Encoded) masks.

In the Matterport Mask R-CNN implementation, all polygonal segmentations are converted to RLE and then converted to masks. Check out annToMask() and annToRLE() in [coco.py](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/blob/8bed8428a9698825de06ff7277fd5cff91aeb77f/samples/coco/coco.py). The reason for the polygons is that they're more efficient to store in json and will shrink the size of the annotation file. If you can't define your shape with a solid polygon, you're stuck with a potentially larger RLE unless you want to make your own custom annotations within COCO and modify your neural net to convert those polygon holes to RLE on your own.

Note that if you are using a neural net that only finds bounding boxes, this is all unneccesary because it won't be capable of returning holes anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I also built [this](https://github.com/MihaiDavid05/Mask-to-COCO-JSON) exporter for instance segmentation, from masks to COCO JSON annotation format, while preserving the holes in the object. With this exporter you will be able to have annotations with holes, therefore help the network learn better.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).